# C# params on method signature doesn't break an override / implementation

Tags: c#, overriding, abstract-class, parameters

I have the following abstract base class:

```
public abstract class HashBase
{
    public abstract byte[] Hash(byte[] value);
}
```

And then I go ahead and implement that class:

```
public class CRC32Hash : HashBase
{
    public override byte[] Hash(params byte[] value)
    {
        return SomeRandomHashCalculator.Hash(value);
    }
}
```

Compile...and it works!

1. Is this advised or does it lead to "evil" code?
2. Is "params" sort of syntactic sugar?

Comment: *“Is "params" sort of syntactic sugar?”* Yep! If you pass an array, it will use that array; if you pass some things that could be elements of an array, it will make those into an array. So it’s compatible; I don’t know about whether it’s advised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look to C# language specification §7.5.3 (overload)

Briefly, i think override keyword is used to redefine an **implementation**, not the parameters. You cant override args, **the args must be the same of abstraction** (im thinking about the liskov substitution principle application here).

Params is totally a syntaxic sugar, it is strictly equivalent to a simple array. It's just more easy to call in certain cases, avoiding array casting; compilator makes the work for you during the method call.

Note that in C# 6, params is going to be compatible with IEnumerable.